# VBA Combine GetOject and GetUsername to return actual name of logged on User instead of code

Tags: vba, excel, object, get

I have two codes, the first picks up a full name (first and Surname) of the user and prints in a display box as "Doe, John".

The second picks up the user ID when they double click on a cell in a defined range and prints the ID as "A012345" with the current time and date.

I would like to combine the two so that instead of ***"A012345 04/04/18 10:19:14"*** 
I get ***"Doe, John 04/04/18 10:19:14"***

**Code 1**

```
Sub Username()
Set objAD = CreateObject("ADSystemInfo")
Set objUser = GetObject("LDAP://" & objAD.Username)
strDisplayName = objUser.DisplayName
MsgBox strDisplayName
End Sub
```

**Code 2**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
Dim i
Dim Myrow As Integer
Dim lpBuff As String * 25
Dim ret As Long, Username As String

ret = GetUsername(lpBuff, 25)
Username = Left(lpBuff, InStr(lpBuff, Chr(0)) - 1)


i = Status

If Not Application.Intersect(Range("E6:N9000"), Target) Is Nothing Then
    If Target = "NA" Then
    Cancel = True
    Exit Sub

    Else
  If Target = vbNullString Then
    Target = Username & " " & Format(Now, "DD/MM/yy HH:MM:ss")
     Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 43
  Cancel = True
Else
    If Target <> vbNullString Then
        Target = ""
        Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
        Cancel = True
    End If
    End If
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You don't need the Hungarian notation also what is GetUsername? Was the top part originally a function you called in the bottom?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

Set objAD = CreateObject("ADSystemInfo")
Set objUser = GetObject("LDAP://" & objAD.Username)
strDisplayName = objUser.DisplayName

If Not Application.Intersect(Range("E6:N9000"), Target) Is Nothing Then
    If Target = "NA" Then
        Cancel = True
        Exit Sub
    Else
        If Target = vbNullString Then
            Target = strDisplayName & " " & Format(Now, "DD/MM/yy HH:MM:ss")
            Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 43
            Cancel = True
        Else
            If Target <> vbNullString Then
                Target = ""
                Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
                Cancel = True
            End If
        End If
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe?

```
Option Explicit

Public Function Username() As String

    Dim AD As Object
    Dim User As Object

    Set AD = CreateObject("ADSystemInfo")
    Set User = GetObject("LDAP://" & AD.Username)

     Username = User.DisplayName

End Function

Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

    If Not Application.Intersect(Range("E6:N9000"), Target) Is Nothing Then

        Select Case Target

        Case "NA"
            Cancel = True
            Exit Sub

        Case vbNullString
                Target = Username & " " & Format$(Now, "DD/MM/yy HH:MM:ss")
                Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 43

        Case Else
                Target = vbNullString
                Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 0

        End Select

        Cancel = True

    End If

End Sub
```